# Capybara webkit redirects me to example.com in RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have an RSPec test suite for my ruby on rails application as follows:

```
scenario "Buyer visits people you follow page" do
   ...do stuff
  end

  scenario "Buyer logs out" do
   ...do stuff
  end

  scenario "Buyer creates a new event", :js => true do
   ...do stuff
  end
```

Before each of these scenarios runs, a background sign_in_as module runs :

```
module SignInHelpers
  def sign_in_as(user = FactoryGirl.create(:user))
    visit welcome_page_url
    save_and_open_page
    fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
    fill_in :user_password, with: "password"
    click_button "Log in"
  end
end
```

All scenarios where I **dont** set :js=>true work fine. The scenario "Buyer creates a new event" javascript is important, so I want to use my webkit which will enable javascript and the capybara page.execute_script method.... the test fails with :

```
Buyer Features Buyer creates a new event
     Failure/Error: sign_in_as
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field :user_email
```

This code runs before all scenarios and works in the previous 8 tests, so why does it fail now?

When I save_and_open_page I realise somehow the test is sitting on example.com! Why is this? I feel if I find out why this is - the problem gets fixed!

This is my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rspec/rails"

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  # Enable debug mode. Prints a log of everything the driver is doing.
  config.debug = false

  # By default, requests to outside domains (anything besides localhost) will
  # result in a warning. Several methods allow you to change this behavior.


  # Allow pages to make requests to any URL without issuing a warning.
  config.allow_unknown_urls

  # Allow a specifc domain without issuing a warning.
  config.allow_url("localhost")

  # Timeout if requests take longer than 5 seconds
  config.timeout = 10

  # Don't raise errors when SSL certificates can't be validated
  config.ignore_ssl_errors

end



Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end


=begin

  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true


  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"


  config.disable_monkey_patching!


  if config.files_to_run.one?

    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end


  config.profile_examples = 10


  config.order = :random


  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

I am assuming the problem is related to something in here, or something that is missing from here, but I cannot work it out!

**Requested routes file **

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :invitations

  post 'utilities/getUserLocation', to: 'utilities#getUserLocation'

  resources :geo_ip_request

  resources :events

  get 'sessions/quick', to: 'sessions#quickBuy', as: "quick_buy"
  get 'sessions/:id', to: 'sessions#show', as: "session"


  post 'sessions/quick', to: 'sessions#getSession'
  post 'sessions/checkin', to: 'sessions#checkin'

  resources :tests

  get '/search', to: 'search#search', as: "search_search"

  get 'welcome/index', as: "welcome_page"



  #get 'sessions/show/:id', to: 'sessions#show', as: "session_show"

  devise_for :users, path: "users", path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', sign_up: 'new/(:invitation_token)' }, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations',  :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}


#resources :users

devise_scope :user do 
 get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
end

get '/users/eventOwner/:id', to: 'users#showEventOwner', as: 'userShowEventOwner'

post  'events/:id', to: 'events#buyTicket'

get 'users/:id/connect', to: 'users#connect', as: "connect_users"

get 'users/confirm', to: 'users#confirm', as: "confirm_users"

get 'users/followers/:id', to:'users#show_followers', as: "show_followers"
get 'users/followees/:id', to:'users#show_followees', as: "show_followees"
post 'users/follow/:id', to: 'users#follow_user', as:"follow_user" 


   #add route to show users favourites collection

   get 'users/favourites/:id', to: 'users#show_favourites', as: 'show_favourites'
   post 'users/favourites/add', to: 'users#add_favourite', as: 'add_favourite'


   patch 'attendees', to: 'attendees#update', as: "update_attendees"

 #get 'users/:id', to: 'users/users#show'
 get 'charges/error', to: 'charges#error', as: "payment_error"
 get 'charges/:id', to: 'charges#show'
 post 'charges/:id', to: 'charges#show'
 post 'charges/', to: 'charges#show'
 get 'listings/:id', to: 'listings#index', as: "listings_index"
 get 'listings/allsales/:id', to: 'listings#all_sales', as: "listings_all_sales"
 get 'listings/allsessions/:id', to: 'listings#all_sessions', as: "listings_all_sessions"



  #ROOT IS LANDING BUT TO BE CHANGED ONCE WE LAUNCH
  root 'landing_page#index'

  #path for landing page

  get '/', to: 'landing_page#index' , as: "landing_page"

#paths for job spec pdfs - controller has click tracking so we can track download numbers
get 'landing_page/download/SEPDF', to: 'landing_page#downloadSEPDF', as: "downloadSEPDF"
get 'landing_page/download/DMPDF', to: 'landing_page#downloadDMPDF', as: "downloadDMPDF"
get 'landing_page/download/SEINTERN', to: 'landing_page#downloadSEInternPDF', as: "downloadSEInternPDF"
get 'landing_page/download/DMINTERN', to: 'landing_page#downloadDMInternPDF', as: "downloadDMInternPDF"

post '/welcome', to: 'welcome#setUserLocation', as: "ajax_Set_User_Location"


   #add route for internal metrics page

   get '/metrics', to: 'metrics#index', as: 'internal_metrics'

   #add route for customer management system

   get 'cms', to: 'customer_management_system#index', as: 'customer_management_system'


 end
```

**UPDATED AS PER SUGGESTION TO GREP FOR EXAMPLE.COM**
A grep was performed for example.com - here are the results:

http://pastebin.com/WgcHcRAg

As you can see - nothing in the source tree (apart from some mailer view content which is irrelevant to this issue) - but a lot of mentions in tmp and capybara....so where is this example.com coming from? It seems to me it is coming from capybara configuration somewhere...

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: Added to the original post :)

Comment: Not sure but if I were you I would grep all files for 'example.com'.

Comment: Added grep contents - doesn't highlight anything obvious apart from capybara seems to somehow have many references to example.com in the tmp folder....the only mentions of example.com in the source tree are from mailer view content which is not relevant to this problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use url helpers with visit, instead use the path helpers.

```
visit welcome_page_path
```

When you use the url helper rails is adding on whatever host and port are specified in its default_url_options setting. The tests worked without js: true because the racktest driver ignores hostnames

Comment: Aha - Ok so that actually fixed it! New problem though!  For some reason the background - sign in as is failing with "Invalid email or password"...odd considering it passes every other previous scenario which works perfectly. Is there something about this new driver which would cause the background module sign_in_as to act differently?

Comment: I would guess you are still using transaction mode for database access.  That doesnt work when capybara is running a server for real browsers to connect to since the tests and app don't have access to the same database connection instance.  You probably need to read the "Transactions and database setup" section of the capybara readme

Comment: Perfect. I installed database cleaner by adding gem "database_cleaner" to the gem file and the suggested config for rspec with capybara :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When using JS with Capybara Webkit, I recommend using a Database cleaner and turning your transactional fixtures to false.

EDIT

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Your application isn't seeing your user in your test database because it is wrapped in a transactional fixture.

Per capybara [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.md#transactions-and-database-setup)...

> Since transactions are usually not shared across threads, this will cause data you have put into the database in your test code to be invisible to Capybara.

You can find more information in the database_cleaner [README](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) under the Rspec/Capybara section.

Comment: How does this answer the question?